# On Boyd et al.'s convergence analysis of ADMM: Why does ADMM not ensure primal variable convergence?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Please refer to [Boyd et al.'s convergence analysis of ADMM](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) (Chapter 3 and Appendix A). In Section 3.2.1, it says that the primal variables $x^k, z^k$ need not converge to optimal values.

Now, as discussed in Section 3.3, ADMM satisfies the dual feasibility condition $0 \in \partial g(z^*) + B^T y^*$ at every iteration, while $0 \in \partial f(x^*) + A^T y^*$ and primal feasibility $A x^* + B z^* - c = 0$ are satisfied in limit.

These 3 conditions are essentially the KKT conditions for the problem (3.1) - see page 13. Also, under strong duality (which is satisfied here - convex problem with affine equality constraint), all the primal-dual solution pairs satisfy KKT conditions (see [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F18/lectures/kkt.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-F18/lectures/kkt.pdf)). Since KKT conditions are being satisfied in the limit here, shouldn't both the primal and dual variables be optimal in the limit as well?

I understand that without additional assumptions, primal objective convergence for general convex functions need not lead to primal variable convergence. But, what am I missing in the reasoning above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were missing is that, $(x^k)$ and $(z^k)$ may not converge at all, without further assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your point. My question is, why does that not follow from the reasoning about KKT conditions and primal-dual solutions, which I mentioned in paragraph 3 of the question?
Also, in the proof of ADMM, the dual residual $s^{k+1} = \rho A^T B (z^{k+1}-z^k) \to 0$. So, at least $(z^k)$ does converge, right?

Comment: There's nothing written in the paper that can deduce the convergence of $x^k$ and $z^k$. The dual residual converges to $0$, but this does not imply that $(z^k)$ converges. A simple example: for the sequence $u_n = \sqrt{n}$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} (u_{n+1} - u_n) = 0$, but obviously $(u_n)$ is not convergent.

Comment: @Pranay_Sharma (I forgot to tag you)

Comment: Oh, right! Completely missed that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Pranay_Sharma You’re welcome! Consider clicking on the Accept button.